# Can Nolzur's Marvelous Pigments be used to open a hole or door through a Wall of Force or Forcecage?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items, terrain, wall

The [Forcecage](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/forcecage) spell states:

> A creature inside the cage can't leave it by nonmagical means.

And its box mode states:

> A prison in the shape of a box can be up to 10 feet on a side, creating a solid barrier that prevents any matter from passing through it

The [Wall of Force](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/wall-of-force) spell states:

> Nothing can physically pass through the wall.

The description of [Nolzur's Marvelous Pigments](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/marvelous-pigments) states:

> When you complete the painting, the object or terrain feature depicted becomes a real, nonmagical object. Thus, painting a door on a wall creates an actual door that can be opened to whatever is beyond. Painting a pit on a floor creates a real pit, and its depth counts against the total area of objects you create.

Can Marvelous Pigments be used to paint a door or hole to go through a Wall of Force or a Forcecage?

Answer (score 9):

As you've identified, the rules are ambiguous here.  It seems to me that the *pigments* operate by transforming the wall behind them into a nonmagical doorway, and that this transformation is magical and would apply to a *wall of force* just as effectively as a nonmagical wall.

But you might also argue that the *wall of force* is a nonphysical object, or that it regrows into the created doorframe, or simply that the doorframe's status as nonmagical means the action just doesn't work.

(It's also not totally clear if you can apply paints on a Wall of Force.  Wouldn't the paints slide off?)

At any rate, when a rules interaction is ambiguous in D&D 5e, the solution is to ask your DM to make a ruling.  We're not your DM, so we can't make that ruling for you.  Good luck with it.

Answer (score 5):

## No.  The door created by the pigment is non-magical.

The pigments create non-magical objects which cannot pass through the barrier.  The door or portal painted on would open up to the barrier.

### *Forcecage* is not affected by normal objects.

Painting a door onto a *forcecage* box would result in the same situation where the area of *forcecage* abutted an existing normal door.  The pre-existing normal objects and terrain features do not affect the spell.  Adding them post-hoc similarly does not affect the spell.

### *Wall of force* cannot be passed through by magical or non-magical objects

The effect of *wall of force* is similarly unaffected as it disallows physical both magical and non-magical objects from passing through:

> Nothing can physically pass through the wall

The painted door opens up to the invisible *wall of force*, which stops passage.

Comment: I'm getting a roadrunner vibe here.

Comment: @NautArch Good point. "Meep meep" should be an obligate vocal component for using painted tunnels.