# Can the Illusion wizard's Illusory Reality feature be used to pass through a Wall of Force or Forcecage?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, class-feature, wizard, illusion

This is a follow-up to another question of mine: [Can Nolzur's Marvelous Pigments be used to open a hole or door through a Wall of Force or Forcecage?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/147404/can-nolzurs-marvelous-pigments-be-used-to-open-a-hole-or-door-through-a-wall-of)

[Illusionist Wizards](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/wizard#SchoolofIllusion) get the [Illusory Reality](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/wizard#IllusoryReality-444) feature at 14th level (PHB, p. 118):

> By 14th level, you have learned the secret of weaving shadow magic into your illusions to give them a semi-reality. When you cast an illusion spell of 1st levei or higher, you can choose one inanimate, nonmagical object that is part of the illusion and make that object real. You can do this on your turn as a bonus action while the spell is ongoing. The object remains real for 1 minute. For example, you can create an illusion of a bridge over a chasm and then make it real long enough for your allies to cross.
>
> The object can't deal damage or otherwise directly harm anyone.

The [Forcecage](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/forcecage) spell states:

> A creature inside the cage can't leave it by nonmagical means.

And its box mode states:

> A prison in the shape of a box can be up to 10 feet on a side, creating a solid barrier that prevents any matter from passing through it

The [Wall of Force](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/wall-of-force) spell states:

> Nothing can physically pass through the wall.

**Can Illusory Reality be used (e.g. by making the illusion of a door real) to pass through a Wall of Force or Forcecage?**

Comment: You might as well ask if Illusory Reality can even create a real door through a mundane wall. If it can't do that, it certainly can't do it for a wall of magical force.

Comment: @Robotex [comments are the place for answers so please refrain from answering in comments](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6533/14878).

Answer (score 3):

## RAW, No

At least not in the way you describe.  The illusion of a door does not breach a wall - be it of brick, stone or force.  It cannot breach the a wall since there is no line of effect to the other side of the wall.  That requires a different kind of magic.

Therefore making a illusory door real would create a real door that opens up onto a wall.

Still, it's kinda neat idea.  I might allow it, as it is creative.