# Can Marvelous Pigments be used to expand the area or volume of a Portable Hole or similar extradimensional space?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items

The description of the [Nolzur's Marvelous Pigments](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/marvelous-pigments) magic item states:

> When you complete the painting, the object or terrain feature depicted becomes a real, nonmagical object. Thus, painting a door on a wall creates an actual door that can be opened to whatever is beyond. Painting a pit on a floor creates a real pit, and its depth counts against the total area of objects you create.

The description of the [Portable Hole](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/portable-hole) magic item states:

> the *portable hole* creates an extradimensional hole 10 feet deep. The cylindrical space within the hole exists on a different plane

Can Marvelous Pigments be used to expand the area or volume of a Portable Hole (or similar extradimensional space, such as the area of a Demiplane spell, a Bag of Holding, a Heward's Handy Haversack, etc.)?

The idea is to open a Portable Hole and then "paint" a pit (or something similar) inside of the hole.

Comment: The related question: [Can Nolzur's Marvelous Pigments be used to open a hole or door through a Wall of Force or Forcecage?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/147404/can-nolzurs-marvelous-pigments-be-used-to-open-a-hole-or-door-through-a-wall-of)

Answer (score 5):

### Maybe

The rule for Marvelous pigments states:

> When you complete the painting, the object or terrain feature depicted becomes a real, **nonmagical** object.

The area of the Portable Hole is a magical item and therefore can't be created or expanded by Marvelous Pigments. This much is very clear.

However, as David Coffron points out, the rule doesn't say the extra-dimensional space created *by* the hole is magical only that it exists on another plane:

> You can [...] place [the hole] on or against a solid surface, whereupon the **portable hole creates an extradimensional hole** 10 feet deep. The cylindrical space within the hole exists on a different plane.

The space created by the object that is the Portable Hole is talked about as a distinct and separate entity by the rule and its existence on another plane does not make that space inherently magical.

In other words, the Portable Hole seems to be a magical item that creates a portal to an extradimensional space that is connected to the item when the item is unfolded but treated separately otherwise. The object is magical, the space is not (and therefore the pigments could be used on it).

It is possible to imagine a person climbing into this extradimensional space and painting a cavity onto the wall of it to expand the space's capacity. One could argue that the rules do not declare that walls exist in the hole but I believe these must exist: the rule on Portable Hole says

> Any creature inside an open portable hole can exit the hole by climbing out of it.

How could a creature climb out of a 10 foot deep hole if there are no interior surfaces? Can you even have a space if there is nothing to delineate it? We've departed from supportable arguments either way at this point.

Therefore, it is difficult to decisively say one way or the other if it is possible to use Marvelous Pigments to achieve something like what you are asking but a DM would not be out of line to rule one way or the other.

Comment: Why couldn't it be a nonmagical closet within the extradimensional space the Portable Hole portals to. The extradimensional space itself isn't magical right?

Comment: Oh. I definitely thought it was about expanding the extradimensiinal space.

Comment: @dav It makes for a better answer either way. Thanks for pointing that out :)

Comment: Wouldn't this suggest that you can always paint an opening to another plane or dimension? The portable hole isn't necessary for this.

Comment: @naut Well, if you are inside the hole that exists on another plane, it would be the equivalent of painting a hole onto a cave all somewhere in Faerun, making the cave bigger. It's not opening space between the planes. This is what I mean.

Comment: But why is the portable hole a necessary bit? If you can paint extra dimensional space, can't you do that anywhere? I think a potential missing piece is painting an extradimensional space (ok?) vs painting an opening into extradimensional space (magical?)

Comment: @naut The OP asks about expanding the capacity of the storage space of the portable hole. That is intrinsic to the question. The painting with the pigments just creates space. You could paint a storage cubby on a wall with it and never open up the portable hole. It wouldn't be extra dimensional and it wouldn't travel with you in the hole.

Comment: So why would painting a bigger edge work? It's seems to me like it's the same thing. Painting on a blank wall or painting on a wall next to the edge of a portable hole.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95436/discussion-between-rykara-and-nautarch).

Answer (score 0):

### No

The portable hole creates an extra-dimensional cylinder-shaped "hole" 6 feet in diameter and 10 feet deep.

This space is not described as having walls - its just a hole into nothing. The pigments require a surface to be painted on and the hole doesn't have any. Just like you can't drive a nail into the side of your hole to hang a picture, you can't paint on those sides either.

Comment: Since the question also mentions other extradimensional spaces, could you include a section on *demiplane* (which does have walls)?